# I am trying to add an image in html using django framework, image does not appear

Tags: html, css, django, web

```
{% extends "basic_app/base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="card text-center">
  <div class="card-body" style="background-color:#F22A00">
    <h5 class="card-title" style="color:black;text-align:center;">TSEC CODESTORM</h5>
    <p class="card-text" style="color:black;text-align:center;">A campus chapter of codecheff</p>
  </div></div>
    <img src="{% static "basic_app/images/hckathon.jpg" %}" alt="Uh Oh, didn't show!">
{% endblock %}
```

This is the code ive used in extended index file however after trying different browsers the image is not visible.
[Here is a screenshot of my webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zmdii.png)

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'j&wblwbdq(i*x+r&l0y96-wv%c5bjopqbgix(0s*i#o32%5r*b'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'basic_app.apps.BasicAppConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_users.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_users.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
]

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTIONS':{'min_length':9}
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'the_directory/static/')]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

# MEDIA INFORMATION:

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

LOGIN_URL = '/basic_app/user_login/'
```

This is the seetings.py file which i have edited and added have a look at it.
Please let me know where i went wrong.
I edited as one of you mentioned but still no results.
I have been stuck at this since a really long time, hope someone helps.

Comment: Are you sure your file name is hckathon.jpg that seems odd like typo, show us your settings also
have you included static urls ->
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development

Comment: Nope the image name is correct,no problem with that

Comment: Try using `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I have had problems like that, it is because I have a problem with the path. In the setting files do you have something like

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'the_directory/static/')]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

then you can have a line like

```
<img src="{% static 'hckathon.jpg' %}" alt="Uh Oh, didn't show!">
```

Where the_directory has the static folder in the folder labled static that is in the same directory as your settings file.

Comment: You will need to use your own directory name instead of the_directory, my last sentence in my answer wasn't that clear.